# connect nodeJS to MySQL when computer is offline

Tags: mysql, node.js, electron

When the computer is offline, then my Electron app can't connect to the local MySQL.
When the computer connected to the internet, everything works fine.
Tested on **Windows only**.
The same happens in nodeJS (command prompt) and in Electron.

code:

```
s = {database: "test", user: "test", password: "test", host: "localhost"}
var mysql = require('./mysql');
var mysqlc = mysql.createConnection(settings);
mysqlc.connect(function(err) { console.log(err); });
```

The error code is:

```
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT localhost:3306]
code: 'ENOENT',
errno: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'localhost',
host: 'localhost',
port: 3306,
fatal: true }
```

Why ?
What can I do about it ?

Comment: I found a discussion of the issue here that may help: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/25489

Comment: @Mike - Thanks! Using 127.0.0.1 realy solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows has an issue with resolving `localhost` to a physical IP address when it is not connected to a network. Apparently what happens is that on Windows is when you give the address `localhost` it passes it to a full DNS resolver which requires a connection to the internet to work properly.

Found a good answer about a possible why here: [Windows 7: “localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself”. Why?](https://serverfault.com/questions/4689/windows-7-localhost-name-resolution-is-handled-within-dns-itself-why)

Try using the IP address itself:

```
s = {database: "test", user: "test", password: "test", host: "127.0.0.1"}
var mysql = require('./mysql');
var mysqlc = mysql.createConnection(settings);
mysqlc.connect(function(err) { console.log(err); });
```